# Tensorflow code for minimizing error between two predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am newly studying tensorflow, and the following code is from one of the class examples:

```
 hiddenBiasUpdate = self.hiddenBias.assign_add(self.learningRate * tf.reduce_mean(hProb0 - hProb1, 0))
```

The interpretation of this code is 'Line 93 updates the hidden bias terms, trying to minimize error between the hidden node outputs from the original data and from the reconstructed data.'

I really don't get it how the code is fulfilling the function it was described.

Here are how hProb0 and hProb1 are defined, I understand them as the predictions for the hidden layer.

```
hProb0 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(self.X, self.weights) + self.hiddenBias)
hProb1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(vProb, self.weights) + self.hiddenBias)
```